# How to guess the vector norm if we have an equation of circle for this norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, normed-spaces, circles

I have some troubles with the following task. We are given the equation:

$$(4t^2-9t+14)y^2 + (-20t^2x-12tz+20x+24z)y+25t^2x^2-4tz^2+11x^2+12xz+9z^2=1$$

The question is for which values of $t$ this equation represents a circle (related to this norm)? And how to compute this norm for arbitrary vector (say, $(1, 1, 1)$)?

As far as I understood, here we have to "guess" somehow what type of norm is that and then transform the LHS of the equation to the needed form, but it's not obvious how to do it. Can you give any hints about the idea of the solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is **this** norm?  Can you clarify the question a bit more?

Comment: @Zvi this is the question -- what is this norm if such a norm exists.

Comment: I think the question is phrased badly.  So, you are looking for a norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that, for some $t$, the equation above represents a spherical surface?  (I don't think it represents a circle for any norm or any $t$.)

Answer (score 1):

Check convexity.

Indeed, the unit ball of any normed space is convex, and conversely, if a (closed/open) convex set is balanced (in case of $\mathbb{R}$ this just means symmetric about 0) and absorbing then it is the (closed/open resp.) unit ball of some seminorm.

Comment: So we should compute the second derivatives over all variables ($x, y, z$) and check that all of them are positive? What if the LHS is convex indeed?

Comment: In this particular problem, since your LHS is a quadratic form in (x,y,z) you just need to diagonalize that form and demand positive definiteness.

Comment: Yes, so for those t for which this expression is positively definite, can we guarantee it will be a norm? How do we find this norm?

Comment: You just "declare" those points on the ellipsoid to have norm 1, and scale.  In other words, when you plug in the point's coordinates into the LHS you will actually get the square of the norm., just like the usual Eucliean norm where you have $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (since the RHS of your equation is $=1$.  If not you will need to divide.)